# Finding Galois group of finite field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $F$ be a finite field and let $K/F$ be a field extension of degree 6. Then the Galois group of $K/F$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ or $C_6$?

Comment: What do you know already about extensions of finite fields? E.g. that they are cyclic?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  oh yes.. surely. I removed other two options i.e. $S_6$ and ${e}$ and was stuck here.

Comment: @ChakSayantan is $S_3$ cyclic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the general result that $\text{Gal}(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p) \cong \Bbb{Z}_n$. This follows from the existence of the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma : \Bbb{F}_{p^n} \rightarrow \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ given by $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^p$ for $\alpha \in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. So in your case, since $[K:F]=6$, the Galois group will be isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $6$.